# How to create transcript using WebVTT file in JWPlayer?

Tags: jquery, html, jwplayer, webvtt, interactive-transcript

We are using JWPlayer in website, now we require to add transcript captioning into that.

I am unable to create a sample application based on normal HTML codes. I have gone through various tutorials but nothing worked for me:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/ramp/nF7Mw/
```

Exactly we want to achieve this type of UI and functionality:

```
http://demo.jwplayer.com/iframes/interactive-transcript/
```

Any guidance would be helpful.

Comment: Your jsfiddle appears to be working. Which aspect of the functionality is not working for you?

Comment: If you view the source of the iframe, you can see the code used, it isn't trivial to add.

Comment: And indeed, the JS Fiddle example works fine, is that yours? If not, do you have a link to where you attempted this?

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer I have simply created three separate files HTML, JS and CSS from JSFiddle example. But that didn't work on my browser as local html. Any idea? OR is there any other example/tutorial I can refer.

Comment: Also I have downloaded all the resources and video files on local machine.

Comment: @Mrunal : in Jsfiddle, it is using jwplayer 6.1, make sure you are using same version... also it will be helpful if you share the issue you are facing or error which is coming in console.... jsfiddle is some one else, I think its not urs (Am I right???)... so please create your own code and share so that we can debug the problem.

Comment: It looks like you got it working :)

Comment: Yeah :)  Now the same fiddle code example is working on my local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got resolved that issue, it was related to local file opening over browser.

I have simply drag and drop my created html file into Chrome browser and checking its output. *(Here url was : file:///mydrive/myfolder/myfile.html)*

Whereas to run this feature, it requires to upload this files on server setup, so I have configured my folder to IIS on my local and then it ran successfully as a URL *(http://mypc/myfolder/myfile.html)*

I couldn't find this on anywhere over tutorials.

Adding this here as an answer, so that it might be useful to someone else.

Comment: As this thing is not mentioned on any of web tutorials, I thought to add here as answer. So that this can be helpful to others.

Comment: Yes, definitely helpful.